# Loop through checkboxes on page and check if its ID is in an array

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to tick a checkbox if their `#id` is in an array.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="chkGroup" id="1" value="1"/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
Administrator
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="chkGroup" id="2" value="2"/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
Responder
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="chkGroup" id="3" value="3"/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
Specialist
</td>
</tr>

var arr = [ 1, 3 ];
var arrGroup = jQuery.makeArray( arr );
$('input[name=chkGroup]').each(function (index, value) {
  if(jQuery.inArray($(value).attr('id'), arrGroup) !== -1) {
    $(value).prop('checked', true);
  }
  else {
    alert($(value).attr('id'));
  }
});
```

It won't tick the box. It only hits the else. Any ideas?

Comment: Do not have numeric ids

Comment: `jQuery.makeArray( arr );` .... `arr` is already an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Do not have numeric IDs - only works in html5
2. Loop over the array instead of the checkboxes

Like this

```
var arr = ["c1", "c3" ];

$.each(arr,function (index, value) {
  $("#"+value).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: I prefer testing for existence first

Comment: Okey, cannot test now. Will go to bed

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try this

```
var arr = [ 1, 3 ];

$("#"+arr.join(",#")).prop("checked", true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/J4HY6/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `inArray` uses a strict equality check (`===`). The ID value being returned is a string; while you're looking for it's numerical value.

Use `parseInt` (and `value.id`; using jQuery just to grab the ID attribute isn't necessary):

```
if(jQuery.inArray(parseInt(value.id, 10), arrGroup) !== -1)
```

**[jsFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Mgkay/)**

Please note that using numeric ID's aren't a great idea; while valid in HTML5, they aren't valid in CSS and may cause you other problems.